# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, `node src/index.js`

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I am working in node Js. When im trying to load a file, with this lines:

```
 key: fs.readFileSync('./localCerts/local.dev.key'),
 cert: fs.readFileSync('./localCerts/local.dev.crt'),
```

This is error appeards when I try to rub application:

> > bou-frontend@0.0.1 start /Users/nikolatrajkovic/Desktop/projects/bou-frontend/bou-frontend
> >     node src/index.js
>
> fs.js:114
>       throw err;
>       ^
>
> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   '/Users/nikolatrajkovic/Desktop/projects/bou-frontend/bou-frontend/build/index.html'
>       at Object.openSync (fs.js:438:3)
>       at readFileSync (fs.js:343:35)
>       at Object. (/Users/nikolatrajkovic/Desktop/projects/bou-frontend/bou-frontend/src/ssr.js:34:22)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
>       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
>       at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18) npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! bou-frontend@0.0.1 start: `node
>   src/index.js` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR!  npm ERR! Failed at the
>   bou-frontend@0.0.1 start script. npm ERR! This is probably not a
>   problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

PACKAGE.json file:

```
scripts": {
    "start": "node src/index.js",
  }
```

Any advice or help is welcome.